# Validating password in JavaScript; RegEx

Tags: c#, javascript, html, regex

On the system I am working with, we have a Password class that validates by throwing exceptions under the following conditions:

```
public Password(string password)
    : base(password)
{
    // Must contain digit, special character, or uppercase character

    var charArray = password.ToCharArray();

    var hasDigit = charArray.Select(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Any();
    var hasSpecialCharacter = charArray.Select(c => char.IsSymbol(c)).Any();
    var hasUpperCase = charArray.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c)).Any();

    if (!hasDigit && !hasSpecialCharacter && !hasUpperCase)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException
             ("Must contain at least one digit, symbol, or upper-case letter.");
    }
}
```

If I was going to write this same check for hasDigit, hasSpecialCharater, and hasUpperCase in JavaScript, what would it look like?

JavaScript does not have these same character prototypes, so I've got to use regular expressions, no?

Comment: The Char.IsSymbol() is non-trivial to implement.  (I just peeked into the mscorlib.dll using the RedGate reflector.)  If you want your javascript and C# implementations to match precisely, you may be better off using the same regular expression on both the client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three conditions can be combined together with:

```
if (/\d|\W|[A-Z]/.test(theString)) {
 ...
```

where

- `\d` → 1 digit (0-9),
- `\W` → 1 non-word character (anything except 0-9, a-z, A-Z and _) *This matches more character than C#'s `IsSymbol`*, in case the password supports characters outside of ASCII,
- `[A-Z]` → 1 uppercase character

but the only characters which doesn't match `\d|\W|[A-Z]` are `a` to `z`, which we may as well simply write

```
if (/[^a-z]/.test(theString)) {
```

Comment: That's different from what the OP asked. You're checking if the password has a digit AND an uppercase AND a specialchar. He wants to check if it has at least one of the three.

Answer (score 1):

hasDigit:

```
/\d/.test(password);
```

hasUpperCase:

```
/[A-Z]/.test(password);
```

hasSpecialCharacter:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(password);
```

**edit** `.test` is much better than `.match`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine all of the tests into one JS regex:

```
if (!passwordString.match(/[^a-z ]/)) {
    alert('Invalid password.');
    return false;
}
```